# ungrouping group by object by taking the first value in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe s which is a group by object:

```
s = df.groupby(['x','y'])
```

I would like to take the first event in each output to a new dataframe,
I have tried:

```
s.first().reset_index()
```

I would like to take the keys of the group by table and putting the values back into a dataframe (ungrouping)

Comment: `df.groupby(['x','y'], as_index=False).first()`?

Comment: yes!! thanks! please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df.groupby(['x','y'], as_index=False).first()
```